# raster to polygon - zero values

Tags: polygon, shapes, raster, shapefile, arcmap

I am trying to convert a raster of cell size 50x50 into a polygon without success.

The raster file has some values and most of them are zero values. When I convert the raster using the tool Raster to polygon, the result is a big polygon for all the values equal to zero, instead of a polygon for each cell with zero value.

Someone knows how to create an independent polygon for each zero value?

I attached an image of my resutls.[image]

Comment: I suppose you do the raster to poly on your ArcGis is that right?

Answer (score -1):

Read this article ... it may solve your problem:

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012696

Steps:

1) Use the **Raster to Point** tool to convert each pixel to a point (found in Conversion Tools > From Raster). These points are later used to label polygons.

2) Navigate to ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Feature Class > **Create Fishnet**. The values entered into this tool are taken from the properties of the raster. To access the properties of the raster, right-click the raster in the Table Of Contents in ArcMap > Properties > Source tab.

3) Navigate to ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Features > **Feature To Polygon**. Run the Feature to Polygon tool on the fishnet output from step 2, with the Raster to Points output specified in the Label Features field. This gives the final polygon which has a field named GRID_CODE with the cell values of the raster.

Comment: Saad Asif, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)